# How to change ES5 -> ES8 JS function syntax?

Tags: javascript

I try to change this (working well) function to be able to run with node + ES8 (without the keyword function), but I can't figure out how to do this.

```
window.getElementsByXPath = function getElementsByXPath(expression, scope) {
    scope = scope || document;
    var nodes = [];
    var a = document.evaluate(expression, scope, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
    for (var i = 0; i < a.snapshotLength; i++) {
        nodes.push(a.snapshotItem(i));
    }
    return nodes;
};
```

(this is a file sourced from node.js to use with puppeeter + chrome headless)

Comment: Are you asking about arrow functions? Did you look at the documentation?

Comment: Sure, but if you don't have a keyword in mind, difficult to search ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the keyword `function` and function name as follow:

```
window.getElementsByXPath =  (expression, scope) => {
  scope = scope || document;
  var nodes = [];
  var a = document.evaluate(expression, scope, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
  for (var i = 0; i < a.snapshotLength; i++) {
    nodes.push(a.snapshotItem(i));
  }
  return nodes;
};
```

**This is called:** Arrow function.

## Resource

- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: How are you going to type if you remove your keyboard? :D

Comment: Thanks Ele, I have to remind _Arrow functions_ now ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax: `var foo = (param) => { // Do stuff }`

With your code:

```
window.getElementsByXPath = (expression, scope) => {
    scope = scope || document;
    var nodes = [];
    var a = document.evaluate(expression, scope, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
    for (var i = 0; i < a.snapshotLength; i++) {
        nodes.push(a.snapshotItem(i));
    }
    return nodes;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go all the way, you could use the iterator type instead of snapshot, make an immediately executing generator, and use the spread and short arrow expression syntax.

```
window.getElementsByXPath = (expression, scope) =>
    [...(function * (iter, node) {
        while (node = iter.iterateNext()) yield node;
    })(document.evaluate(expression, scope || document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null))];
```

Not that this makes it more readable though...

The `function` keyword reappears, as generators can currently not be written with arrow syntax.